# Dynamically selecting column based on if that column exists in another column's value (Java Spark SQL)

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I am using Spark SQL Java (Not scala or python). Here is a simplified example of my dataset (it has many more columns than this):

| ID | References | E_id | F_id | G_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [E_id] | 0000 |  |  |
| 1 | [E_id, F_id, G_id] | 0010 | 1000 | 1111 |

There is a column called `References` which contains an array of column names that this row of data has. So the first row only has a `Ex_1` column and would not have the columns `Ex_2` or `Ex_3` while the second row has all 3 columns. For each row, I need to select relevant columns (Like `References` and `ID` which all rows of data have) and then also select the respective columns that are included in `References`.

At the moment, this is my code:

```
final Dataset<Row> partitionedDf = df.select(col("id"), col("references));
```

I can't hardcode any of the `Ex_1, Ex_2...etc` columns into my select because the possible columns inside References are dynamic. I need to figure out a way to get References for each row and then select the columns inside References as well so it's all included in my Dataset.

**One thing to note is that the columns inside reference do all follow a pattern (they all end with "_id") so I'm not sure if regex matching could be used here as well, rather than relying on what is inside the References array.**

Comment: how many columns are there, why not catch all of them and then take the arry and extract the data that you want, so sql isn't made for dynamics

Comment: I agree with @nbk. This sounds like something that should be done in `Java` code. Read all the data from the table and store it in an object and use code `If-statements` or `streams` to extract data or do what you need.

Comment: What's the expected output? Your are saying "also select the respective columns that are included in References". All rows of a dataframe always have the same columns though. Dataframes are basically tables. Therefore, for a given row, what should be done if the reference column does not contain a given column? Set it to null?